# Why the getApplication() from Service Class on android can still return its sub class obj?

Tags: java, android

As the title,

I've seen the code below in a custom service class of KiahApplication to acquire app's Application obj:

`((KiahApplication)super.getApplication()).setServiceRunning(true);`

But how could `android.app.Service` class's getApplication method know & return my custom Application obj?

`android.app.Service` should not be a part of my custom application,

and it's not recorded in the Application's manifest file which should be the definition of the App's members.

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: what do you mean with "Service class should not be a part of my custom application" ? Every single app has a single Application class. And every Activity, Service or other Context has access to it. Whenever an Activity or Service is created this Application is also available

Comment: I mean that `android.app.Service` shouldn't be a part of my custom app right? Then how does it get my custom Application obj?

Answer (score 1):

`super.getApplication()`
call getApplication in the super class, which is `android.app.Service`

`((KiahApplication)super.getApplication())`
cast result of `super.getApplication()` to `KiahApplication`, which is `class KiahApplication extends Application`

`((KiahApplication)super.getApplication()).setServiceRunning(true);`
call `setServiceRunning(true);` on the KiahApplication class

> But how could Service class's getApplication method know & return my custom Application obj?

Because it's a singleton. Anywhere you call `getApplication()` it will return the same everywhere: the KiahApplication instance. `getApplication()` can be called on a Context. A Service is a Context and can therefore call the method.

Note that the `super` in the call is not needed.

Comment: Castelijins Thank you so much for helping, but to my understanding singleton means to limit the number of the instance to only one, in this case I'm wondering why the `android.app.Service`, which shouldn't the part of any custom app, can obtain my custom `KiahApplication` obj? What's the foundation for deciding which classes are members of an app & can obtain the app obj? Isn't it the app's manifest xml file? Also actually the code I saw uses both `super.getApplication()` & `getApplication()`, which means there'll still be two `KiahApplication` instances at the same time. Appreciate!

Comment: @Kiah any object that is a `Context` can retrieve the Application instance (which is a singleton). A `Service` is a `Context`, so it can retrieve the Application instance

Comment: *Also actually the code I saw uses both super.getApplication() & getApplication(), which means there'll still be two KiahApplication instances at the same time.*, no they just get it twice. It is the same instance that they retrieve